# Generic class property

Tags: c#, generics

i need make a property of my class generic .. i have a json and sometimes the object property can arrive with null value.
Example :

sometimes she can arrive like this:

```
{
        "id": 111047,
        "name": "TV",
        "active": true,
        "id_category": 318,
        "parent": {
           "id": 111046,
           "name": "LCD",
           "active": true,
           "id_category": 317,
           "parent": null,
           "sellerId": null
       },
       "sellerId": 50
}
```

and sometimes like this:

```
{
  "id": 111046,
  "name": "LCD",
  "active": true,
  "id_category": 317,
  "parent": null,
  "sellerId": 50
}
```

i try this :

```
public class CompleteCategory
{
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string active { get; set; }
        public string id_category { get; set; }
        public CompleteCategory? parent { get; set; }
        public string sellerId { get; set; }
}
```

but he give me this error :

> Error 1   The type 'CompleteCategory' must be a non-nullable value type
>   in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'System.Nullable'

i would like know, how i can make this ??

Comment: That error is telling you that CompleteCategory is already a class and not a value type. This means that CompleteCategory is already nullable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just omit the `?` after the type name (`CompleteCategory`).  It's a `class`, so it is already nullable.  The `?` character is used to make a non-nullable type nullabe, but, as the error message says, it cannot be used on a type that is already nullable.

The type does not need to be generic at all to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the nullable sign '?' to this : `public CompleteCategory parent { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

`CompleteCategory` is a class (i.e. a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx)), so it can be null.
On the other side value types (like int or DateTime) can't be null (so in this case you can use `?` to force their "nullability")

So just delete the `?` from your property declaration.

Comment: *Most* value types can't be null, but there are exceptions.  C# has nullable value types (specifically, `Nullable<T>` is a nullable value type).

Comment: You're right, but I consider `Nullable<T>` a "workaround" to make value types nullable. Do you know other exceptions?

Comment: Well, there are pointers.  How you try to categorize them is...difficult.